# Best Way to Format Time Respecting Locale and User's 24-hour Preference

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to format a time display to conform to both the current Locale, and the device user's 24-hour clock preference. Here is what I'm currently doing, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

```
val time = ZonedDateTime.now()
val formatter = when (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) {
    true -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
    false -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
}

text = time.format(formatter)
```

Is there any way to get the user's 24 hour preference aside from using `DateFormat` (since that class is obsolete)?

Is there a better way to create the formatter? `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)` doesn't respect the user's 24 hour preference.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nothing better than what I already have unfortunately. What I have does work though.

Comment: The method you're using is good but I have an international app and this method doesn't work with all locales. For example, some countries use a `-` instead of `:` as an hour-minute separator that's why I have to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime()` since it handles all cases (except user's 24-hour settings ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but this is what I came up with. It *should* retain any locale-specific formatting (as in the comment by [@HeysemKatibi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839334/heysem-katibi)) while switching between 12 and 24-hour formats, but I haven't tested it throughly.

Really wish `DateTimeFormatter` respected the user settings and/or there was an easy way to tell it to switch to 24-hour time.

```
fun Context.formatTime(time: TemporalAccessor): String {
    var pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        null,
        FormatStyle.SHORT,
        IsoChronology.INSTANCE,
        Locale.getDefault()
    )

    if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)) {
        pattern = pattern.replace("h", "H")
            .replace("a", "").trim()
    }

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)

    return formatter.format(time)
}
```

Comment: Oh this is better than what I had. Still hoping for a way to ditch `DateFormat` though!